# Installed xcfe yesterday, woke up to my DE being all kinds of screwed up. Any clues?

Tags: 20.04, display-resolution, desktop-environments

so, I'm a Windows user coming to Ubuntu for emulation. Installation was tough since my monitor is VGA and my system has both an AMD CPU and GPU so I had to to it in 640x480. Then I've used cvt to set up a custom resolution and it worked nicely. Then I've installed xcfe yesterday, as my machine doesn't run all too well under GNOME. At some point during the same day, I had to restart, and so I did, through the UI. However, an error came up before the system rebooted, I can't recall right now what it said. And then, I woke up today, booted, chose Ubuntu (I'm dualbooting) and this came up. Am supposing that error had something to do with it. Any clues??

[image: my DE]

My specs:

GPU: RX Vega 11
CPU: Ryzen 5 3400G
RAM: 2x4GB 2400MHz
MOBO: A320M-HD
PSU: generic 350W

Comment: Regardless of the DE (Desktop Environment) you need to have proper graphics drivers installed. Please post the hardware specifications.

Comment: @ChanganAuto editted my specs in

Comment: Drivers for AMD graphics are already included and should just work. But for new hardware you also need a brand new release like 20.04 (with HWE kernel) or even 21.04. The RX Vega 11 may even need a newer kernel that what comes with the latest release.

Comment: so should I just dump the OS I'm using and install 21.04 instead?

Comment: I suggest you try with a live session first. If it works as expected then yes, I think you should try. BTW, which Ubuntu have you installed?

Comment: My system has AMD cpu and gpu, and it ran fine with a vga monitor at full resolution (that was pop os, so it could be that system76 removed that glitch) So why lower your resolution?

Comment: Check what do the lines `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` & `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the file: `/etc/default/grub` say. Add `quiet splash nomodeset=1`, in the existing line (along with the existing content) & see if it works. If you can get past this screen, go to `Software & Updates` from `Main` menu & under the tab `Additional Drivers` check if the system is using the recommended driver. If not, choose the correct one (install, if not already there) & restart and see.